# Can Laplace solve every lineair differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I'm learning about laplace tranform method to solve lineair differential equations but i'm wondering if laplace transformations can be used to solve every linear differential equations there is.
Or are there some limitations?

I know that for the operator method the equation has to be from the form: $e^at$ / $sin(bt)$ / $cos(bt)$ and Polynomial.

Comment: Some MSE users tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: If the coefficient is not constant, it may be difficult to solve using Laplace transform. For example $y'(t)=y(t)\cos t$.

Answer (score 4):

One can say without any problem that almost no equation can be solved using Laplace transforms. There are two main reasons for this. One is that in general Laplace transforms cannot be computed, unless for functions with some prescribed growth. Otherwise nothing can be done. Even worse, one often writes a symbol for the Laplace transform of the solution without knowing whether the solution has that prescribed growth (still one can say that if at the hand we find a solution of which one can compute the Laplace transform, the reasoning is correct).
The other main reason is of course that the method expects that we are able to compute explicitly, and like finding primitives this is more art than mathematics.

A minor secondary reason is that the method has difficulties dealing easily with the situation when the initial conditions are not numbers...

I would say that there is absolutely no reason why we should use the method of Laplace transforms, in general for each problem there are much better methods.

Comment: Honest question...why do we teach them?

Comment: Honest answer: my personal impression is that we shouldn't, at the level of undergraduate courses. But I have been there! :-) I taught them often at an engineering school because the syllabus was fixed (with the justification that they were useful in engineering). But they may be taught at a higher level, also as a particular class of integral transforms.

Comment: I learned about them briefly in undergrad. I took differential equations late, after seeing some Fourier analysis and I couldn't see any appeal over Fourier transform. I've never used or seen them since. I never thought about it really.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a function without a Laplace transform, such as $e^{e^x}$. Then:

$$y'(x)=e^{e^x}$$

can't be solved by taking Laplace transforms.

Comment: Do you mean laplace transform doesnt exist for functions like $e^{f(x)}$? or specifically that function? why or why not? These answers would be helpful to other people like me....

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong. I think its because that function climbs faster than $e^{-st}$ so the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$ will not convert to 0. This counts for every function which climbs faster than the exponential function. So $e^{e^t}$ or $t^t$ ...

Comment: can you explain why?